# stripping pandas dataframe index of '\n' and whitespaces

Tags: python, pandas

After obtaining the data from a html response, and feeding it through pandas Dataframe with the below code, I transpose the data and print the results.

```
r1 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml').prettify()
r3 = pandas.read_html(r1, header=None, index_col=None)[0]
r3.dropna(inplace=True)

r4 = pandas.DataFrame.transpose(r3)

r5 = r4.index

print(r5)
```

i get the below result.

```
Index(['\n                     ',
       '\n                      2006-12\n                     ',
       '\n                      2007-12\n                     ',
       '\n                      2008-12\n                     ',
       '\n                      2009-12\n                     ',
       '\n                      2010-12\n                     ',
       '\n                      2011-12\n                     ',
       '\n                      2012-12\n                     ',
       '\n                      2013-12\n                     ',
       '\n                      2014-12\n                     ',
       '\n                      2015-12\n                     ',
       '\n                      TTM\n                     '],
      dtype='object')
```

How do I strip all the `'\n'` and `white spaces` in this index to just have the digits and TTM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
In [98]: i
Out[98]:
Index(['\n                     ', '\n                      2006-12\n                     ', '\n                      2007-12\n
       ',
       '\n                      2008-12\n                     ', '\n                      2009-12\n                     ', '\n
        2010-12\n                     ',
       '\n                      2011-12\n                     ', '\n                      2012-12\n                     ', '\n
        2013-12\n                     ',
       '\n                      2014-12\n                     ', '\n                      2015-12\n                     ', '\n
        TTM\n                     '],
      dtype='object')

In [99]: i = i.str.replace(r'[\n\s]+', '')

In [100]: i
Out[100]: Index(['', '2006-12', '2007-12', '2008-12', '2009-12', '2010-12', '2011-12', '2012-12', '2013-12', '2014-12', '2015-12', 'TTM'], d
type='object')
```

Better solution from [@Joe Lin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178803/stripping-pandas-dataframe-index-of-n-and-whitespaces/42179405?noredirect=1#comment71521891_42179405):

```
In [103]: i.str.strip()
Out[103]: Index(['', '2006-12', '2007-12', '2008-12', '2009-12', '2010-12', '2011-12', '2012-12', '2013-12', '2014-12', '2015-12', 'TTM'], d
type='object')
```

Comment: `i.str.strip()` may be simpler.